# Way to create a frozen table-view in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, wxwidgets

I've got an SQLite table with potentially hundreds of thousands of entries, which is being added to (and occasionally removed from) in the background at irregular intervals. The UI needs to display this table in an arbitrary user-selected sorted order, within a wxWidgets `wxListCtrl` item.

I'm planning to use a `wxLC_VIRTUAL` list control, and query the table for small groups of items as needed using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, but I foresee trouble. When the background process makes changes to items that are "above" the currently-viewed ones, I can't see any way to know how the offsets of the currently-viewed items will change.

Is there some SQLite trick to handle this? Maybe a way to identify what offset a particular record is at in a specific sorted order, without iterating through all of the records returned by a `SELECT` statement?

Alternatively, is there some way to create an unchanging view of the database at a particular time, without a time-consuming duplication of it?

If all else fails, I can store the changed items and add them later, but I'm hoping I won't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by creating a query to find the index of an item, by counting the number of items that are "less than" (in the user-defined order) the one I'm looking for. A little complex to write, because of the user-defined ordering, but it works, and runs surprisingly fast even on a huge table.